# Python indentation syntax error -- if/else tree

Tags: python, syntax

I got an error in the printing program I wrote.

```
from variables import *    
li = []
for i in range(len(word)):
    if i in graph:
        for j in graph[i]:
            if j in graph[i]:
                li.append(len(graph[i][j])
            else: # line 23
                li.append(0)
    else:
        for j in range(len(word)):
            li.append(0)
    print li
    del li[:]
```

The error is

```
File "eval.py", line 23
else:
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not throwing it away. I'm just deleting its contents. The list still exists. Please take your attempt at sarcasm elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a paranthesis.

```
li.append(len(graph[i][j])
```

should be

```
li.append(len(graph[i][j]))
```